# How would I parse this type of JSON using SwiftyJSON?

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

```
[

  {

    "ID": 0,

    "Name": "PHI"

  },

  {

    "ID": 0,

    "Name": "ATL"

  }

]
```

I'm using SwiftyJSON and Alamofire. This is what is being returned. I want to loop through each of these objects now in my code. I'm having trouble getting this information though.

json[0]["Name"].string seems to return nil, and I'm not sure why. The JSON object is definitely getting the JSON, when I print it to the console it looks exactly like above.

I also tried:

```
var name = json[0].dictionary?["Name"]
```

Still nil though.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Here's the code I'm using to retrieve the JSON.

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "url", parameters: nil, encoding: .JSON, headers: nil).responseJSON 
{
    (request, response, data, error) in
    var json = JSON(data!)
    //var name = json[0].dictionary?["Name"]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried printing `json[0]` ?

Comment: Yeah, json[0] is also nil.

Comment: If json[0] is nil then I believe there is something wrong with the formatting and/or retrieval

Comment: Can you post all of the code you're using from retrieving the data to trying to parse it?

Comment: I just added the code I'm using for retrieval to my original post.

Comment: What's weird when I test this is that the JSON is valid and the method to access the SwiftyJSON object is working (`json[0]["Name"].string` gives me optional "PHI"), *but* your Alamofire example didn't compile, I had to change the signature.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is valid (at least this snippet is), and your first method to retrieve the data from SwiftyJSON is correct.

On the other hand, the Alamofire snippet you showed didn't compile for me, I had to change the signature.

Given that in the comments you say that not only `json[0]["Name"]` is nil but `json[0]` is *also* nil, I think you have a problem with how your data is fetched.

I tested this version of the Alamofire method in a sample app and it worked well:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, yourURL).responseJSON(options: nil) { (request, response, data, error) in
    let json = JSON(data!)
    let name = json[0]["Name"].string
    println(name)
}
```

[image]

*In the screenshot, the URL is my local server, with your JSON copy pasted in "test.json".*

*This "answer" is an extension of my comment, I needed room to show more info...*

Comment: Hmm.. if I format my request the way you did with my URL, it doesn't return the JSON anymore. data is nil.

Comment: Ok. I guess we're using different versions of Alamofire, then. And maybe there's something else on your side. // I think now you should debug a bit more on your side and check every step that could look good but actually be wrong (classic trap). Something like 1- verify with Alamofire *alone* that it returns data. 2- verify that this data is your valid json. 3- can you print the result with NSJSONSerializtion? 4- can you do it with SwiftyJSON? Etc.

Comment: if you print the json object, what does it look like for you? Mine looks like this: [{"ID":0,"Name":"Philadelphia"},{"ID":0,"Name":"NFL"}]

Comment: I've got the [same](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s89/sh/f05a9f8d-b8a2-49cb-9ca5-a3cc6f2c430e/a83adeeb23aaa42c/res/0b3fbf1a-c491-4076-b5d6-7ae7e7c28a8b/skitch.png), only difference is it's "pretty printed" (indented).

Comment: By the way, just to confirm that it's something else on your side: I just pasted `[{"ID":0,"Name":"Philadelphia"},{"ID":0,"Name":"NFL"}]` from your comment in my "test.json" file and your code still works, I get the name correctly.

Comment: Hint: you can verify that the json data you get from Alamofire is valid like this: `print(NSJSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(data!))`

Comment: This is a frustrating one. `let jsonObj = JSON(json)
                println(jsonObj)
                println(jsonObj[0]["Name"].string)` .. This returns the JSON I showed you above, but the second print prints nil.

Comment: Interesting.. that isValidJSONObject is returning false for me.

Comment: Cool! "Cool" because know we're sure that, although the JSON you get *looks like* it's ok (to an human eye), it's actually not. So now you narrowed the problem. Usual suspects: invisible characters, bad encoding utf8/ascii/etc, smart double quotes instead of normal ones, etc.

Comment: So you think it's most likely that it's actually a problem with my API?

Comment: Yes. I mean: given that the JSON snippet from this question is valid, and the example code in the question does work with it, then yes, it's very likely a problem with your actual complete JSON data/response. I think we've now assessed that what is presented on this page works well, so the problem is from elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might try this.

first convert JSON(data) using swifyJSON

```
           let json = JSON(data!)
```

then count the array element in data.

```
                let count: Int? = json.array?.count
```

after that use for loop to reach array element one.

```
  for index in 0...count-1 {

         self.idArray.append(json[index]["ID"].stringValue)

        self.nameArray.append(json[index]["Name"].stringValue)
               }
```

you will get sorted data in "idArray" and "nameArray". try to print both the array.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use index to parse array. You can get single json object from array and use it to access the data:

```
for (index: String, subJson: JSON) in json {
    println("Current Index = \(index)")

    if let _id = subJson["ID"].int {
        println("ID = \(_id)")
    } else {
        println("Error ID")
    }

    if let _name = subJson["Name"].string {
        println("Name = \(_name)")
    } else {
        println("Error Name")
    }   
}
```